# How to subset data using grep in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a really straightforward question. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
dat
        ROI    Band2    Band3    Band4
1      red_2 0.037923 0.036316 0.015526
2      red_3 0.045340 0.032751 0.018201
...
11     bcs_2 0.045742 0.014596 0.009815
12     bcs_3 0.028775 0.011336 0.006283
...
```

And I want to be able to select to select all of the rows based on the string `red` or `bcs`.

So far I have the code:

```
grep("^red_", dat$ROI, value = TRUE)
```

Which returns:

```
[1] "red_2"  "red_2"  "red_2"  "red_2"  "red_3"  "red_3"  "red_3"  "red_3"  "red_4"  "red_4"  "red_4" 
[12] "red_4"  "red_5"  "red_5"  "red_5"  "red_5"  "red_6"  "red_6"  "red_6"  "red_6"  "red_7"  "red_7"
```

But what I really want is a  vector that returns a column of only the `red` or `black` rows, for example:

```
        ROI    Band2    Band3    Band4
1      red_2 0.037923 0.036316 0.015526
2      red_3 0.045340 0.032751 0.018201
```

~~ Thanks for solving my problem! I now have a slightly different data frame that looks like this:

```
dat
    X    ROI        Band      Min      Max     Mean    Stdev
1   1  red_2      Band 1 0.032262 0.124425 0.078073 0.028031
2   2  red_2      Band 2 0.021072 0.064156 0.037923 0.012178
3   3  red_2      Band 3 0.013404 0.066043 0.036316 0.014787
```

And I'm wondering how to select all the red values in the `ROI` column and all the Band 1 values in the `Band` column?

Comment: Use `grepl`. `dat[grepl("^red_", dat$ROI),]`

Comment: I knew it was easy! Thanks!!!

Comment: `dat[grep("^red_", dat$ROI, value=FALSE),]` should also work.

Comment: Thanks @Psidom and @Marcelo! I altered the question slightly. Could you please help?

Comment: `dat[grepl("^red_", dat$ROI) & dat$Band == "Band 1",]` depending on what the AND means here. You might want `dat[grepl("^red_", dat$ROI) | dat$Band == "Band 1",]`

Comment: Ah, I mean to select only the rows which have `Band 1` in the Band column. Will fix the question.

Comment: @Psidom I get the error message `error in `[.data.frame`(dat, grepl("^red_", dat$ROI) | Band == "Band 1",  : 
  object 'Band' not found`

Comment: @Psidom The first option returns with the `&` returns `[1] X     ROI   Band  Min   Max   Mean  Stdev
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` and the second one returns all of the rows. I wonder if it does not like the space in-between Band and #?

Comment: You can print out `dat$Band` and see what kind of string you have there.

Comment: It looks like a matrix with four levels: `Band 1` `Band 2` `Band 3` and `Band 4`

Comment: Does your code work for you @Psidom?

Comment: It works as I would expect for your given example.

Comment: For some reason this works but not your latest code: `dat[grepl("Band 1", dat$Band) & grepl("^red_", dat$ROI),]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137458/discussion-between-jag2024-and-psidom).